# Magento 2 how to update requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, overrides, payment-methods, payment, requirejs-config.js

We are using the Magento 2.3.5 version we want to update the version from 3.79.1 to 3.97.0 in requirejs-config.js

file-path - vendor/gene/module-braintree/view/base/requirejs-config.js

when we are override in our theme with an updated version - app/design/frontend/Infortis/base/Magento_Paypal/requirejs-config.js

Then in the browser view page source it is showing 2 times instead of 1.SO it is not override it just add new there.

How to override requirejs-config.js ?

Comment: please add your requirejs-config.js code here.

Comment: here i asked in different way - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/370547/magento-2-update-braintree-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your overriding requirejs-config.js file in

```
app/design/frontend/<your-vendor>/<your-theme>/Magento_BrainTree/
```

Also, note that this will override only for frontend. As the file to be overriden is a base file, if you want it overridden in adminhtml as well you have to copy the file in your adminhtml theme as well.

```
app/design/adminhtml/<your-vendor>/<your-theme>/Magento_BrainTree/
```

Comment: When we checked in frontend via the view-page-source then 2 times are coming

Comment: For any change to reflect for requirejs-config.js we need to run both setup:upgrade and static content deploy commands. Have you run both of them?

Comment: yes i run both commands still it is showing 2 times